# Why does Python's hash() generate a collision between these two close numbers?

Tags: python, hash

Why does Python's native `hash()` generate a collision for `-1` and `-2`?

```
>>>> hash(-1)
-2
>>>> hash(-2)
-2
```

My understanding is that Python's `hash` will simply output the exact value of the number fed in - this seems to hold upto `2^60` and `-2^60`:

```
>>>> hash(2**8)
256
>>>> hash(-2**8)
-256
>>> hash(2**60)
1152921504606846976
>>> hash(-2**60)
-1152921504606846976
```

What is special about `-1` in this instance?

Comment: AFAIR `-1` is the internal value for an error and so can't be used.